# Combining alert conditions in Graylog

Tags: graylog2, graylog

I am wondering if it is possible to combine two alert conditions, for example MessageCount and FieldContent, to send an alarm callback when there is more than 5 messages in a minute that have specific field content. 
Is it even possible to make a plugin to do that? 
Thanks in advance.